# How trim the spaces given in a word for textField

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a word i.e., P roduct Name in a textfield . we have to trim the space between "P" and "r".

Can you please suggest the solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure you will always be having a space, which you want to remove, only at index 1?

Comment: No accepted answer, no vote. How could that happen? Are the provided answers really THAT bad?

Comment: This can help you to remove spaces between two words.

NSString *string = @"P roduct Name"; NSString *secondString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

Output: ProductName

If You want to remove white spaces at start and end of your string

NSString *s = @" Product Name "; s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Output: 'Product Name'

Answer (score 2):

There is no real reliable solution for this - there is not enough information provided.

(Unless of course you iterated through a word list, which would be, well, horribly inefficient)

`P` and `r` could be separate words for all the computer cares..

Comment: I'd like to add: how should an algorithm decide whether the space in `P roduct` should be removed, but not the space in `roduct name` ? The only solution would be a word list, as Jacob said (instead of iterating one could make use of the Levenshtein distance to speed up searching but it'd still be a lot of work and resource itensive).

Answer (score 0):

This can help you to remove spaces between two words.

NSString *string = @"P roduct Name";
NSString *secondString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

Output: ProductName

If You want to remove white spaces at start and end of your string

NSString *s = @"  Product Name ";
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Output: 'Product Name'